# Chartist js chart displaying incorrectly

Tags: chartist.js

I'm creating a chart using chartist.js, and am using the FixedScaleAxis to control exactly the points on my y axis.

```
var data = {
  labels: [ "1995",
                           "1996",
                           "1997",
                           "1998",
                           "1999",
                           "2000",
                           "2001",
                           "2002",
                           "2003",
                           "2004",
                           "2005",
                           "2006",
                           "2007",
                           "2008",
                           "2009",
                           "2010",
                           "2011",
                           "2012",
                           "2013",
                           "2014",
                           "2015"],
    series: [
    [ 2.92,
                                 2.83,
                                 2.69,
                                 2.57,
                                 2.4,
                                 2.27,
                                 2.19,
                                 2.15,
                                 2.06,
                                 2.06,
                                 1.92,
                                 1.82,
                                 1.8,
                                 1.76,
                                 1.72,
                                 1.71,
                                 1.61,
                                 1.56,
                                 1.52,
                                 1.41,
                                 1.35]
  ]
};

var options = {
  height:400,
  seriesBarDistance: 100,
  axisY : {
             type : Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
             ticks : [ 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0 ]
            }
};

new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

But when I do and add a height the x axis displays within the chart rather than below it. Please see the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnhpwn8x/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `high`/`low`, `referenceValue` and `scaleMinSpace` instead. Those are pretty self-explanatory, `low` is the lowest value on the axis, `high` is the highest value, `referenceValue` is a value that is always shown. `scaleMinSpace` is the minimum distance between two lines on that axis.

```
axisY : {
      low: 1.2,
      referenceValue: 3,
      scaleMinSpace: 40
        }
```

[Fiddle example on the above.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnhpwn8x/22/)

But if you just want the chart to scale to show all of the data, you could just specify `scaleMinSpace`, and the rest will happen automatically. [Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnhpwn8x/21/)